Changing R Temporary Files
I built custom functions for sequential resampling, clipping, and writing raster stacks from CHIRPS, Modis, and ERA5. After considering that I work over an extensive area and long temporal period (which causes huge rasters), I've set the working and temporary directories to E:// which have 770 GB. However, after performing the function (twice), my C:// decreased drastically from 172 to 15 GB.
Any idea to modify the function? or I was wrong in the first place?
# Load necessary libraries
library(terra)
library(progress)

setwd("E:/KLHK/KHG/1_Riau/R")

# Set the temporary directory for R's file usage
tempdir_custom <- "E:/KLHK/KHG/1_Riau/R"
# Ensure the temporary directory exists
if (!dir.exists(tempdir_custom)) {
  dir.create(tempdir_custom, recursive = TRUE)
}
message("Temporary directory set to:", tempdir_custom)

# Sequential resampling function with memory management and flexible resolution
sequential_resample <- function(raster, final_resolution = 10, method = "cubicspline") {
  current_res <- res(raster)
  resampled_raster <- raster  
  # Halve the resolution until the largest side reaches <= 2x final resolution
  while (max(current_res) > 2 * final_resolution) {
    target_res <- current_res / 2
    temp_target <- rast(ext(raster), res = target_res, crs = crs(raster))
    resampled_raster <- resample(resampled_raster, temp_target, method = method)
    current_res <- res(resampled_raster)
  }    
  # Final resampling to the exact final_resolution value
  final_target <- rast(ext(raster), res = c(final_resolution, final_resolution), crs = crs(raster))
  resampled_raster <- resample(resampled_raster, final_target, method = method)    
  return(resampled_raster)
}

# Function to resample, clip, stack, and write raster data
resample_clip_stack_write <- function(
  raster_data, 
  output_directory, 
  tempdir_custom, 
  final_resolution = 10, 
  extent = NULL, 
  method = "cubicspline",
  stack_name = NULL
) {
  # Ensure the output directory exists
  if (!dir.exists(output_directory)) {
    dir.create(output_directory, recursive = TRUE)
    message("Created directory:", output_directory)
  } else {
    message("Directory already exists:", output_directory)
  }  
  # Set up a temporary directory for intermediate operations
  tempdir(tempdir_custom)
  message("Temporary directory set to:", tempdir_custom)  
  # Initialize an empty list to store resampled and clipped raster layers
  resampled_layers <- list()  
  # Iterate over each layer in the raster stack
  for (i in 1:nlyr(raster_data)) {
    message(paste("Processing layer", i, "of", nlyr(raster_data)))    
    # Access the layer by index
    raster_layer <- raster_data[[i]]    
    # Apply sequential resampling
    resampled_layer <- sequential_resample(raster_layer, final_resolution, method)    
    # Clip the resampled layer if an extent is provided
    if (!is.null(extent)) {
      message("Clipping layer to extent...")
      if (inherits(extent, "SpatVector")) {
        resampled_layer <- crop(resampled_layer, extent)
      } else if (inherits(extent, "SpatRaster")) {
        resampled_layer <- mask(resampled_layer, extent)
      }
      message("Clipping complete.")
    }    
    # Store the processed layer
    resampled_layers[[i]] <- resampled_layer
  }  
  # Combine all processed layers into a single SpatRaster stack
  stacked_raster <- rast(resampled_layers)
  message("All layers combined into a single SpatRaster stack.")  
  # Determine the output file name
  output_file <- file.path(
    output_directory, 
    ifelse(is.null(stack_name), "Processed_Stack.tif", paste0(stack_name, ".tif"))
  )  
  # Write the resulting stack to disk
  writeRaster(stacked_raster, output_file, overwrite = TRUE)
  message("Stacked raster written to:", output_file)  
  # Return the stacked raster as an in-memory SpatRaster object
  return(stacked_raster)
}

# Define AOI or raster for clipping
aoi_Riau <- vect("E:/KLHK/KHG/1_Riau/1_input/AOI/PHU_bound_10km.shp")  # Vector extent (AOI)

# Set the output directory and other parameters
output_res_riau <- "E:/KLHK/KHG/1_Riau/3_olah2/1_CHRIPS"

# Call the function to process rasters
res_Riau_precip_2021 <- resample_clip_stack_write(
  raster_data = Riau_precip_2021,
  output_directory = output_res_riau,
  tempdir_custom = tempdir_custom,
  final_resolution = 10,  # Target resolution
  extent = aoi_Riau,  # Shapefile AOI or raster for clipping
  method = "cubicspline",
  stack_name = "Riau_Precip_2021_Stack"  # Optional name for the resulting stack
)

thank to Chris, I clarified the background.
the code example above is for resampling, clipping, and writing CHIRPS stacks (precipitation) only.
The initial Riau_precip_2021 stack (containing 24 rasters) only accounts for 264 KB in my E:// disk with the resulting resampling stack is 18.9 GB. this is not my concern since I already prepared E:// as primary storage for all resampled stacks.
find R still uses C://Users/.../AppData/Local/Temp to save their temporary rasters (yes it is the problem) before it stacked and written to my E:/. I want the temporary folder to be moved to this path:
tempdir_custom <- "E:/KLHK/KHG/1_Riau/R"

Any idea ?

I think that mentioning 1) the resolutions of  CHIRPS, Modis, ERAS5 you're working with (so we don't have to go get some to remind ourselves), 2) where those are located (presumably E:/KLHK/KHG/1_Riau/R), 3) rationale for keeping initial rast(s) instead of overwriting to ROI in place, 4) final ROI...  It seems there's a lot of embedded 're-doing' in the approach, while in then end a stack rast::c( is desired putting all the inputs within, CHIRPS, Modis, ERAS5, unless I'm misreading the flow. So, a little more statement of the desired output?

@Chris I've clarified my question

changing where my tempdir is, which may suggest re-titling your question for additional clarity, and do note you'll want to execute these changes prior to starting your working session.

tempdir(tempdir_custom) does not at all do what you think it does. You need to read the documentation.

thank you, I've changed the title accordingly

You seem to think that this changes the R tempdir:
# Set up a temporary directory for intermediate operations
  tempdir(tempdir_custom)

But it does not. tempdir only returns the temporary directory path. I think you can only set the tempdir path before starting R (via a configuration file).
The good news is that, since your interest is in temporary files created by "terra", you can do
terraOptions(tempdir=tempdir_custom)


You saved me, I am testing it now

it works perfectly
